# getDownloadUrl from FirebaseStorage using Thread in java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, firebase-storage

In my code I'm trying to get Uri for Firebase Storage references using Threads (for making a queue):

```
public class GetThemeThread implements Runnable {
    private volatile Article article;
    private final StorageReference reference;
    private Context context;

    public GetThemeThread(StorageReference reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Print1: " + reference);
        reference.child("title.jpg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                System.out.println("Print2: " + uri.toString());
                article = new Article(reference.getName(), uri);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    public Article getArticle() {
        return article;
    }
}
```

List of references is formed before in previous Activity. And I'm sure that it was formed correctly (have already checked it). And I also ensure that this file in Firebase reference exists. But it doesn't work in such variant((  It gets nothing (null) instead of Uri.... It prints the reference correctly in a line "Print1", but doesn't print anything in line with "Print2".
Previosuly I tried using Task instead of Thread with the same code and it worked correctly.

Comment: getDownloadUrl is already asynchronous, so it doesn't make much sense to put it in its own thread.  The Task callbacks (success and failure listeners) deliver the result back to the main thread. If you don't see anything printed from either callback, maybe something is blocking the main thread.  Modern Android applications should generally have no need for Thread or Task, preferring instead LiveData and other utilities for managing async work.